# Not able to understand the Pattern Matcher example in Java

Tags: java, regex

Can someone simplify the following line in pattern:
Following piece of code is removing trailing zeroes but I am not able to understand it.

The String threshold is 299.0 and out put is 299.

```
public static String removeTrailingZeros(String threshold) {
    Pattern thresholdPattern = Pattern.compile("([\\.,]0)($|\\s+)");
    Matcher match = thresholdPattern.matcher(threshold);
    threshold = match.replaceFirst("$2");
    return threshold;
}
```

Why are we doing "match.replaceFirst(**"$2"**);"
I am not able to understand it's significance.

And how is it able to find the trailling zerores?

It does not replace 299.00 with 299 ? If I want to do that, what can I do to accomodate both 299.0 and 299.00?

Answer (score 1):

$1, $2... $n in regular expression replaces are references to the matches wrapped in parenthesis.  $0 would be the entire match, $1 would be the first parenthesized capture, $2 would be the second, and so on..

```
 Pattern thresholdPattern = Pattern.compile("([\\.,]0*)($|\\s+)");
```

It will remove any number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: And how is it able to find the trailling zerores?

Comment: It does not replace 299.00 with 299 ? If I want to do that, what can I do to accomodate both 299.0 and 299.00?

Comment: @Naresh I have edited the answer according to your question.

Comment: 1. Can you please explain this ""([\\.,]0" regex? I understand u have put "*", 2. could this be a problem for numbers like : 200.003? 200.03? 200.30?

Comment: @Naresh 1. [\\.,] will match characters after "." , [\\.,]0 It make sure that after "." only 0 should match . 2. It will work for every input.

Answer (score 1):

`$2` is a [**numbered replacement backreference**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the value captured with the second [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Your pattern matches:

- `([\.,]0)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) matching a `.` or `,` and then a single `0` char
- `($|\\s+)` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern) matching either the end of string (`$`) or 1 or more whitespace chars (`\s+`).

If you only use `$2` in the replacement, it means the Group 1 value is discarded, and only Group 2 value is kept.

You may avoid using backreferences in the replacement pattern if you use a [**lookaround**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (a negative lookahead `(?!\S)`):

```
public static String removeTrailingZeros(String threshold) {
    return threshold.replaceFirst("[.,]0+(?!\\S)", "");
}
```

Note you do not need to escape a `.` inside the characterc class. Here, the `[.,]0+(?!\S)` pattern matches:

- `[.,]` - a [**character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching either `.` or `,`
- `0+` - 1 or more consecutive occurrences of `0`
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a char other than whitespace (`\S`) immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

`$2` is a reference to the second capturing group, in this case `($|\s+)`. The effect is to preserve trailing whitespace, if present. It seems to be using whitespace as a primitive and somewhat confusing way to detect word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify will be using this code

```
String example = "299.00";
example = example.replaceAll("\\\\.0+", "");
```

Answer (score -1):

see [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) for grouping and use this code:

```
inputStr.replaceFirst("^(\\d+)(((!?)[\\.,])([0]*))(\\$|\\s*)$", "$1$6");
```

input strings sample :

```
"299." & "299.00" & "299.000" & ... change to  => "299"

"299.$" & "299.00$" & "299.000$" & ... change to  => "299$"

"299.001" & "299.010" & "299.0001$" & ... not change
```

also you can see it in [here](https://regex101.com/r/Zw5uda/1).